# wxpython pubsub fails after loading from dill

Tags: python-3.x, dill, wxpython

I use wxpython (phoenix) as frontend and wx.lib.pubsub to manage the inter-module (and inter-package) messaging in my program. I currently use the module dill to save and load the program state.

I only use the sendMessage and the subscribe methods, no fancy tricking here.

If I stay in the same session, that is, I build the model and modify it without saving and reloading the model, all works fine.
However, when restarting the GUI and starting a session from a saved file, part of the messaging that worked previously OK, fails: the messages are sent, but the receiver does not get them. 
When directly calling the methods that should have been called on the receiver side, all works great, regardless of the session.

Due to the complexity of the problem I can't really provide an example, but would appreciate any effort for clarification or shared similar experiences.

Answer (score 0):

To kind of answer my own question: after trying to reproduce the issue in toy problems unsuccesfully followed by lenghty debugging the source of the problem was found to be the way certain properties were set, namely using property.setters. These have been replaced by set_ methods and the issue was resolved.

I know this question and also the answer are well below the expected SO standard, feel free to downvote.